How to Retrieve Card ID After Completing Setup in Stripe Payment Sheet?
I'm trying to achieve and setup with Stripe Payment Sheet. after complete card setup how to get card id
    STPAPIClient.shared.publishableKey = publishableKey

      // MARK: Create a PaymentSheet instance
      var configuration = PaymentSheet.Configuration()
      configuration.merchantDisplayName = "Example, Inc."
        configuration.customer = .init(id: customerId, ephemeralKeySecret: customerEphemeralKeySecret)
      configuration.allowsDelayedPaymentMethods = true

     self.paymentSheet = PaymentSheet(setupIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent, configuration: configuration)

paymentSheet.present(from: vc) { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .completed:
                
            case .canceled:

            case .failed(let error):

            }
        }


Why do you need card ID client-side after placing an order? If you need to store that after an order, you should use webhooks and take care of that server-side: https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=ios&mobile-ui=payment-element#ios-post-payment.
